# Problem in displaying html tables horizantally

Tags: html, css

Actually i want to display these 2 tables horizontally on my GUI.But not able to display them properly.Can u please look into my code? and how can i display these two tables horizontally?
This is my code link : http://jsfiddle.net/Yr7km/

Comment: You are using same ID `tableContainer` for a div, this will definitely result in wrong UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any cross browser and **correct** solution. I would go with **ancient style** code and put them in a third table.

The fast fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yr7km/15/

I've added some CSS to make it more visible. I've added HTML comments with a lot of `*` to mark my edits too.

Thre is `display: table-something` in CSS. Unfortunately IE has problems with this. [w3schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_display.asp) You may play with floats, however it may be problematic sometimes.

Comment: Actually i tried,but not able to display it properly,Can u please tell me How my code will look like?

Comment: I've added link to fiddle in my answer.

Comment: No offence but aren't you using table for layout and intimidating him/her to go into dark ages?

Comment: @Kumar Yes. It isn't my fault some versions of IE are too popular.

Comment: you made me laugh :), +1 to you :P

Answer (score 1):

I would be doing some thing like this

```
<div id="container">
<div id="table1">put your table here</div>
<div id="table1">put your table here</div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

In CSS
    `#container{ width: 100%;}`
    `#table1{ width: 50%; float: left; display: block;}`
    `#table2{ width: 50%; float: right; display: block;}`
    `.clear{ clear: both;}`
This is minimum markup and CSS that should give you an idea how to layout elements.